# Why is $L=\{w~|~\#_a(w) \ge \#_b(w)\}○\{w~|~\#_a(w) \le \#_b(w)\}$ regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, context-free

Why is this language regular: $L=\{w~|~\#_a(w) \ge \#_b(w)\}○\{w~|~\#_a(w) \le \#_b(w)\}$?

Where $\#_a(w)$ is defined as the number of $a$ in $w$.

Isn't that a concatenation between 2 CFL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of this concatenation is $\Sigma^*$, which is regular.

I will leave it to you to verify this is the case.

Comment: I assumed that this is $(a+b)^*$, but I am not sure that I understand why, and how is that possible that concatenation between 2 CFL that are not Regular gives us a regular language. Thank you Nir!

Comment: There is no guarantee about concatenation of non-regular languages *not* being regular itself. This is something important to remember, since you can get confused really easily otherwise

Comment: You are correct, thank you for mentioning that! :)